# How to automate Keystore generation using the java keystore tool? w/o user interaction

Tags: java, keystore

I am trying to automate keystore generation using the Java keystore tool. The command I am using is :

```
keytool -keystore keystore -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA
```

But after this command, user is required to enter certain inputs as follows:

```
Enter keystore password:  password
What is your first and last name?  
[Unknown]:  jetty.mortbay.org  
What is the name of your organizational unit?  
[Unknown]:  Jetty  
What is the name of your organization?  
[Unknown]:  Mort Bay Consulting Pty. Ltd.  
What is the name of your City or Locality?  
[Unknown]:  
What is the name of your State or Province?  
[Unknown]:  
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?  
[Unknown]:  
Is CN=jetty.mortbay.org, OU=Jetty, O=Mort Bay Consulting Pty. Ltd.,  
L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?  
[no]:  yes  

Enter key password for <jetty>  
(RETURN if same as keystore password):  password
```

Instead of the user entering these values , is there any way of providing these values without user interaction ,either within the command or through a script?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you read these informations from a property file ?

Comment: There are more command line options - read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html (including distinguished name)

Comment: Just because the example used a local address, doesnt mean this issue is localised.  I am un UK and just had the same question.  Fortunately, because some answered the question before it was closed, it just saved me a load of time trying to work out the answer.

Comment: This question was very useful and the answer helped out.  Don't understand why it was closed.

Comment: Yet another example of trigger happy SO moderators ready to jump the gun at a moment's notice on closing actual, relevant, and useful questions so they can exercise the small amount of power they have to make themselves feel important. This was the first result when I searched this question on Google and it helped me solve my issue, unbelievable that it was closed simply because it referenced the asker's locale in the question.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Try this:

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt \
 -alias alias1 \
 -dname "CN=mqttserver.ibm.com, OU=ID, O=IBM, L=Hursley, S=Hants, C=GB" \
 -keystore keystore \
 -storepass password \
 -keypass password \
 -keyalg RSA
```

Comment: is there a way to specify source keystore password when importing a .p12 keystore into a .jks?

Comment: @ErikAllik `keytool -importkeystore [...] -srcstorepass password_here`

Comment: Don't forget the -keyalg flag or this script will fail.

Answer (score 18):

don't forget -noprompt, otherwise you will be asked to input Yes or No

Comment: if someone else had the same problem that there was a prompt even with this option: there are some commands that have -srckeypass and -srcstorepass. you may easily mix them

Answer (score 6):

See the [full documentation about command line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)   or by typing `keytool` without any arguments.

Specifically you may want to look options `-storepass password -keypass password`

Comment: -dname keyword is needed too