# HTML: how to deploy applet (preferably .jar file)

Tags: java, html, web-applications, jar

As the title explains it, I need to deploy a java app inside html document.

I tried:

```
<applet code=Gume.class 
    width="120" height="120">
</applet>
```

and:

```
<applet code=Gume.class 
    archive="dist/Gume.jar"
    width="400" height="600">
</applet>
```

It would be optimal, if I could deploy .jar file (aplication was made with NetBeans and the index.html file is in root of the application's folder).

Comment: You need to place your jar file next to the html file, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: But the .jar file is in dist folder. I tried placing it next to html, still doesn't work. When i run html in browser (tried Mozilla, Chrome and IE), it says: Your security have blocked a local application from running.

Comment: With recent Java update (well not so recent anymore) Java stepped up the security. You'll need to sign your jars and everything.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187520/signing-jar-file

Comment: have signed it, and it displays the following:  Your security have blocked a selfsigned application from running