# Access denied JNLP file

Tags: java, javafx, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to run my JNLP file. I've created ExecutableJar of my JavaFX application, and signed it with the `jarsigner` command. My jnlp file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" href="myjnlp.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>MyApplication</title>
        <vendor>Me</vendor>

    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="myapp.jar"
            main="true" />
    <security>
                <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    </resources>

    <application-desc
         name="MyApplication"
         main-class=
           "pl.package.Main"
         width="300"
         height="300">

     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.preloader" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.preloader" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$158(LauncherImpl.java:130)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:129)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:252)
    at pl.package.Main.main(Main.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The jar file runs without any problems, but when I try to run jnlp file, which basically in my understanding tries to execute the jar file, then the problem appears.
What am I doing wrong??

Main.java

```
package  pl.package;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;


public class Main extends Application {

    static Stage window;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

             window = primaryStage;
             Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MainScreen.fxml"));

             Scene scene = new Scene(root);
             scene.getStylesheets().add("/application.css");
             window.setTitle("Diffraction and Interference");
             Main.window.setResizable(false);
             window.setScene(scene);
             window.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
package pl.package;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;

import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCell;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;



public class MainController  {

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;

    @FXML
    private HBox hbox;

    @FXML
    private TextField slitsNumber, intensity, slitsDistance, lambda, distanceScreen; 

    @FXML 
    private LineChart<Number, Number> chart;

    @FXML 
    private NumberAxis xAxis;

    @FXML
    private  NumberAxis yAxis;

    @FXML
    private Button chartBtn, moreBtn;

    @FXML
    private  int slits;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem closeItem, saveItem, excelOpen, aboutProgram, moreURL, settings;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton chartPhase, chartTheta, chartY;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup group;

    @FXML
    private double d, theta, I0, L, waveLambda;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar menubar;
    double max = 0;


    @FXML
    private Slider mySlider;

    @FXML 
    private Node rect1,rect2, rect3, rect4, rect5;;

    @FXML
    private Button waveColorButton;

    @FXML
    private  ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLUE);


    @FXML
    private Arc arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4, arc5, arc6, arc7, arc8, arc9, arc10, arc11;

    @FXML
    private Arc arc12, arc22, arc32, arc42, arc52, arc62, arc72, arc82, arc92, arc102, arc112;

    @FXML
    private Arc arc13, arc23, arc33, arc43, arc53, arc63, arc73, arc83, arc93, arc103, arc113;

    @FXML
    private Arc arc14, arc24, arc34, arc44, arc54, arc64, arc74, arc84, arc94, arc104, arc114;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle slitRectangle1, slitRectangle2, slitRectangle3, slitRectangle4, slitRectangle5, slitRectangle6, slitRectangle7, slitRectangle8, slitRectangle9, slitRectangle10, slitRectangle11;

    private ArrayList<Arc> circleList1 = new ArrayList<Arc>();
    private ArrayList<Arc> circleList2 = new ArrayList<Arc>();
    private ArrayList<Arc> circleList3 = new ArrayList<Arc>();
    private ArrayList<Arc> circleList4 = new ArrayList<Arc>();

    private ArrayList<Rectangle> slitList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    double phase, phase2;
    double width, min, submax;
    String widthParse, minParse, submaxParse;

    double[] tableY = new double[401];

    private RadioButton selectedRadioButton;
    private String toogleGroupValue;
    private Boolean dataEntered = false;

    int excelCounter = 0; 
    boolean startOrStopValue = false; 
    int defaultStroke = 1;


    public void initialize() throws InterruptedException  { 

        rectangleList.add((Rectangle)rect1);
        rectangleList.add((Rectangle)rect2);
        rectangleList.add((Rectangle)rect3);
        rectangleList.add((Rectangle)rect4);
        rectangleList.add((Rectangle)rect5);

        animatePlainWave(rect1,0);
        animatePlainWave(rect2,1.4);
        animatePlainWave(rect3,2.8);
        animatePlainWave(rect4,4.2);
        animatePlainWave(rect5,5.6);

        circleList1.add(arc1);
        circleList1.add(arc2);
        circleList1.add(arc3);
        circleList1.add(arc4);
        circleList1.add(arc5);
        circleList1.add(arc6);
        circleList1.add(arc7);
        circleList1.add(arc8);
        circleList1.add(arc9);
        circleList1.add(arc10);
        circleList1.add(arc11);

        circleList2.add(arc12);
        circleList2.add(arc22);
        circleList2.add(arc32);
        circleList2.add(arc42);
        circleList2.add(arc52);
        circleList2.add(arc62);
        circleList2.add(arc72);
        circleList2.add(arc82);
        circleList2.add(arc92);
        circleList2.add(arc102);
        circleList2.add(arc112);

        circleList3.add(arc13);
        circleList3.add(arc23);
        circleList3.add(arc33);
        circleList3.add(arc43);
        circleList3.add(arc53);
        circleList3.add(arc63);
        circleList3.add(arc73);
        circleList3.add(arc83);
        circleList3.add(arc93);
        circleList3.add(arc103);
        circleList3.add(arc113);

        circleList4.add(arc14);
        circleList4.add(arc24);
        circleList4.add(arc34);
        circleList4.add(arc44);
        circleList4.add(arc54);
        circleList4.add(arc64);
        circleList4.add(arc74);
        circleList4.add(arc84);
        circleList4.add(arc94);
        circleList4.add(arc104);
        circleList4.add(arc114);

        slitList.add(slitRectangle1);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle2);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle3);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle4);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle5);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle6);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle7);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle8);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle9);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle10);
        slitList.add(slitRectangle11);

        slitList.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT));  
        rectangleList.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));
        rectangleList.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        circleList1.forEach((n) -> animateCircle(n,0)); 
        circleList1.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(null)); 
        circleList1.forEach((n) -> n.toBack());
        circleList1.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));

        circleList2.forEach((n) -> animateCircle(n,1)); 
        circleList2.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(null)); 
        circleList2.forEach((n) -> n.toBack());
        circleList2.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));

        circleList3.forEach((n) -> animateCircle(n,2)); 
        circleList3.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(null)); 
        circleList3.forEach((n) -> n.toBack());
        circleList3.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));

        circleList4.forEach((n) -> animateCircle(n,3)); 
        circleList4.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(null)); 
        circleList4.forEach((n) -> n.toBack());
        circleList4.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));

        chart.setTitle("Intensity Interference Pattern");
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        yAxis.setTickUnit(10);

        group = new ToggleGroup();
        chartPhase.setToggleGroup(group);
        chartTheta.setToggleGroup(group);
        chartY.setToggleGroup(group);
        chartPhase.setSelected(true);

    }

    @FXML
    public void parsing () {

            try {
                I0 = Double.parseDouble(intensity.getText());
                System.out.println("Io: " + I0);

                d = Double.parseDouble(slitsDistance.getText());
                System.out.println("d: " + d);

                L = Double.parseDouble(distanceScreen.getText());
                System.out.println("L: " + L);

                waveLambda = Double.parseDouble(lambda.getText());
                System.out.println("waveLambda: " + waveLambda);

                slits = Integer.parseInt(slitsNumber.getText());
                System.out.println("Slits number entered: " + slits);

                if(slitsCheck()==true && startOrStopValue == true)
                {
                    activateSlits(slits);
                }


                dataEntered = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                showDialog("Data Entered Error Message", "Every textfield must me filled!" + "\n" + "Only numbers can be entered!");

            }

    }

    public boolean slitsCheck()
    {
        if(slits<1 || slits>11)
        {
            showDialog("Data Entered Error Message", "Slits number must be between 1 and 11");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    @FXML
    public void drawChart(ActionEvent e) {
        if(dataEntered) {
            selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.getSelectedToggle();
            toogleGroupValue = selectedRadioButton.getText();
            chart.setTitle("Intensity Interference Pattern" + " " + toogleGroupValue );

            chart.getData().clear();
            System.out.println("Drawing chart is begining...");
            xAxis.setLabel("Phi [rad]");
            yAxis.setLabel("Intensity [W/m^2]");

            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> data1 = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();

            double n = -200;
            double j = -200;

            tableY[0] = 0;

            if(chartPhase.isSelected()) {
                System.out.println("Phase chart starts drawing...");
                for(int i = 0; i < 401; i++) {
                    tableY[i] = I0*(Math.sin(slits*0.5*n))*(Math.sin(slits*0.5*n))/((Math.sin(0.5*n))*(Math.sin(0.5*n)));
                    n += 0.01;
                    j++;
                    data1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(j, tableY[i]));
                }

            }else if(chartTheta.isSelected()) {
                System.out.println("Theta chart starts drawing...");
                for(int i = 0; i < 401; i++) {
                    tableY[i] = I0*(Math.sin(slits*d*Math.sin(n)*Math.PI/waveLambda))*(Math.sin(slits*d*Math.sin(n)*Math.PI/waveLambda))/((Math.sin(d*Math.sin(n)*Math.PI/waveLambda))*(Math.sin(d*Math.sin(n)*Math.PI/waveLambda)));
                    n += 0.01;
                    j++;
                    data1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(j, tableY[i]));
                }
            }else if (chartY.isSelected()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 401; i++) {
                    tableY[i] = I0*(Math.sin(slits*d*n/(waveLambda*L)))*(Math.sin(slits*d*n/(waveLambda*L)))/((Math.sin(d*n/(waveLambda*L)))*(Math.sin(d*n/(waveLambda*L))));
                    n += 0.01;
                    j++;
                    data1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(j, tableY[i]));
                }
            }

            yAxis.setUpperBound(max*1.1);
            data1.setName(slitsNumber.getText());
            chart.getData().add(data1);
            chart.setLegendVisible(true);
            chart.setCreateSymbols(false);

            }else {
                System.out.println("Data entered missing");
                showDialog("Data Message", "Please, type data in every texfield!" + "\n" + "Use only whole numbers!");
            }

    }

    public void openWindow() {
        System.out.println("Trying to open a second window...");
        try { 

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/SecondScreen.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();


        SecondController secondController = loader.getController();

        this.calculate();
        secondController.setCalculations(widthParse, minParse, submaxParse);


        Stage newWindow = new Stage();
        newWindow.setTitle("Calculations");

        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 640,480);

        newWindow.setScene(scene2);
        scene2.getStylesheets().add("/application2.css");

        newWindow.show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Data missing");
            System.out.println("Catched: " + e);
            showDialog("Data Missing Message", "Please, type data in every texfield!" + "\n" + "Use only numbers!");
        }      
    }

    public void calculate() {
        phase = 360/slits;

        //theta in degrees
        theta = phase*waveLambda/(d*360*1000000)*180/Math.PI;
        width = 2*theta;
        widthParse = Double.toString(width);

        //minimum in mm
        min = phase*waveLambda*L/(d*360*1000);
        minParse =Double.toString(min);

        //submax in degrees
        try {
            phase2 = 2*360/(slits-1);
            submax = Math.asin(phase2*waveLambda/(d*360*1000000))*180/Math.PI;
            submaxParse = Double.toString(submax);

        }catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("N cannot be 1 when calculating subsidiary maximum!");
            System.out.println("Catched: " + e);
            if(slits == 1) 
                showDialog("Calculating subsidiary maximum error","2nd subsidiary maximum does not exist");

        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void closeProgram() {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @FXML
    public void saveAsPng() {
        System.out.println("Chart saving starts...");
        WritableImage image =chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
            System.out.println("Saved in: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to save ");
            System.out.println("Catched: " + e);
        }
    }


    @FXML
    public void info() {
        showDialog("About program", "Program shows the diffraction and interference on N slits (diffraction grating).");

    }


    public void showDialog(String title, String text) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(text);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }


    @FXML
    public void saveExcel() throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
    {
        boolean doWeHaveAllInts = true;
        try 
        {
            Integer.parseInt(slitsDistance.getText());
            Integer.parseInt(slitsNumber.getText());
            Integer.parseInt(intensity.getText());
            Integer.parseInt(lambda.getText());
            Integer.parseInt(distanceScreen.getText());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            doWeHaveAllInts = false;
        }

        if(doWeHaveAllInts == true) 
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Excel workbook saving starts...");
                WritableWorkbook myFirstWbook = null;
                File file = new File("resources/workbook"+excelCounter+".xls");
                myFirstWbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);   
                WritableSheet excelSheet = myFirstWbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);

                Label label = new Label(0, 0, "Distance between slits");
                jxl.write.Number number = new jxl.write.Number(0,1,Integer.parseInt(slitsDistance.getText()));
                excelSheet.addCell(label);
                excelSheet.addCell((WritableCell) number);

                label = new Label(1, 0, "Slits number");
                number = new jxl.write.Number(1,1,Integer.parseInt(slitsNumber.getText()));
                excelSheet.addCell(label);
                excelSheet.addCell((WritableCell) number);

                label = new Label(2, 0, "Wave intensity");
                number = new jxl.write.Number(2,1,Integer.parseInt(intensity.getText()));
                excelSheet.addCell(label);
                excelSheet.addCell((WritableCell) number);

                label = new Label(3, 0, "Wavelength");
                number = new jxl.write.Number(3,1,Integer.parseInt(lambda.getText()));
                excelSheet.addCell(label);
                excelSheet.addCell((WritableCell) number);

                label = new Label(4, 0, "Distance to screen");
                number = new jxl.write.Number(4,1,Integer.parseInt(distanceScreen.getText()));
                excelSheet.addCell(label);
                excelSheet.addCell((WritableCell) number);

                myFirstWbook.write();
                myFirstWbook.close();
                System.out.println("Saved in: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                showDialog("Information", "Saved in: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            catch (Exception e) //tutaj taki wyjatek a nie IOException, bo mozliwy wyjatek to RuntimeException, ktory sie pojawia jak chcemy zapisac stringa zamiast inta
            {
                System.out.println("Unable to save ");
                System.out.println("Catched: " + e);
            }
            excelCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            showDialog("Warning","Please enter only numerical values");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadExcel() throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
    {

        System.out.println("Excel workbook loading starts...");
        Workbook workbook;
        File file = null;
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());     
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            try
            {
                file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file); //tu byl jakis warning o static-accesie ale go jakos (?) naprawilem

                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                Cell cell0 = sheet.getCell(0, 1);
                slitsDistance.setText((cell0.getContents()));

                Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(1, 1);
                slitsNumber.setText((cell1.getContents()));

                Cell cell2 = sheet.getCell(2, 1);  
                intensity.setText((cell2.getContents()));

                Cell cell3 = sheet.getCell(3, 1);  
                lambda.setText((cell3.getContents()));

                Cell cell4 = sheet.getCell(4, 1);  
                distanceScreen.setText((cell4.getContents()));   
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You didn't select a file");
        }

    }

    @FXML
    public void changeWaveColor()
    {    
        rectangleList.forEach((n) -> n.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue()));
        circleList1.forEach((n) -> n.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue())); //wlaczenie animacji
        circleList2.forEach((n) -> n.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue()));
        circleList3.forEach((n) -> n.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue())); //wlaczenie animacji
        circleList4.forEach((n) -> n.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue()));

    }

    public void animatePlainWave(Node rectangle, double seconds)
    {
        TranslateTransition rectangleTransition = new TranslateTransition();
        rectangleTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(rectangle.getLayoutY()/100)); //czas jaki trwa animacja
        rectangleTransition.setToY(850-rectangle.getLayoutY()); //koniec drogi
        rectangleTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        rectangleTransition.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE); //zapetlenie
        rectangleTransition.setNode(rectangle);
        rectangleTransition.rateProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(1d, mySlider.valueProperty()));
        rectangleTransition.setDelay(Duration.seconds(seconds));
        rectangleTransition.play();
    }


     @FXML
     private void activateSlits(int n)
     {
         circleList1.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
         circleList2.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
         circleList3.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
         circleList4.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
         slitList.forEach((m)->m.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT));
         rectangleList.forEach((m)->m.setStrokeWidth(2));

         for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
         {

             circleList1.get(i).setStrokeWidth(1);
             circleList2.get(i).setStrokeWidth(1);
             circleList3.get(i).setStrokeWidth(1);
             circleList4.get(i).setStrokeWidth(1);
             slitList.get(i).setFill(Color.WHITE);

             if(n%2==0)
             {

                 circleList1.get(0).setStrokeWidth(0);
                 circleList2.get(0).setStrokeWidth(0);
                 circleList3.get(0).setStrokeWidth(0);
                 circleList4.get(0).setStrokeWidth(0);
                 slitList.get(0).setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);


                 circleList1.get(n).setStrokeWidth(1);
                 circleList2.get(n).setStrokeWidth(1);
                 circleList3.get(n).setStrokeWidth(1);
                 circleList4.get(n).setStrokeWidth(1);
                 slitList.get(n).setFill(Color.WHITE);
             }

         }

     }


     private void animateCircle(Arc arc,double seconds)
     {
            final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(arc.radiusXProperty(), 500);
            final KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(arc.radiusYProperty(),500);
            final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(6), kv);
            final KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(6),kv2);

            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
            timeline.setDelay(Duration.seconds(seconds));
            timeline.rateProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(1d, mySlider.valueProperty()));
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf2);

            timeline.play();
      }

     @FXML
     private void startOrStopAnimation()
     {
         if(dataEntered == true)
         {
             if(startOrStopValue==true) //stop
             {

                 rectangleList.forEach((n) -> n.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                 rectangleList.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));
                 circleList1.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
                 circleList2.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
                 circleList3.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
                 circleList4.forEach((m) -> m.setStrokeWidth(0));
                 rectangleList.forEach((n) -> n.setStrokeWidth(0));
                 slitList.forEach((m)->m.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
                 startOrStopValue=false;

             }
             else
             { 
                 if(slitsCheck()==true) //start
                    {
                        activateSlits(slits);
                    }
                 startOrStopValue=true; 
             }
         }
         else
         {
             showDialog("Error","No data");
         }

     }

     public void openWindowThree() {
            System.out.println("Trying to open a third window...");
            try { 
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/ThirdScreen.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            ThirdController thirdController = loader.getController();

            Stage newWindow = new Stage();
            newWindow.setTitle("Find out more");

            Scene scene3 = new Scene(root, 960,540);

            newWindow.setScene(scene3);
            scene3.getStylesheets().add("/application3.css");

            newWindow.show();
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Catched: " + e);
            }      
        }
     @FXML
    public void toURL() {
        openWindowThree();
    }

}
```

SecondController.java

```
package pl.package;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SecondController {

    @FXML
    private Label centralMax;
    @FXML
    private Label firstMin;
    @FXML
    private Label subMax;

    @FXML
    private Label centralMaxLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label firstMinLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label subMaxLabel;

    public void initialize() {

    }
    public void setCalculations(String centralmax, String firstmin, String submax){
        centralMaxLabel.setText(centralmax);
        firstMinLabel.setText(firstmin);
        subMaxLabel.setText(submax);
    }
}
```

ThirdController.java

```
package pl.package;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class ThirdController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    @FXML
    private Button reloabBtn;

    private WebEngine engine;



    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        engine = webView.getEngine();
    }

    public void loadURL(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Opening page...");
        engine.load("https://opentextbc.ca/physicstestbook2/chapter/multiple-slit-diffraction/");
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the code part ?

Comment: @AnishB. I added the whole exception. I don't think that there is a need to add the whole project, which is quite big, because the jar file runs without any problems.

Comment: just add a part of the java code.

Comment: @AnishB. Just added the whole java part.

Answer (score 0):

Update xml file to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" href="myjnlp.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>MyApplication</title>
        <vendor>Me</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="myapp.jar"
            main="true" />
    </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <application-desc
         name="MyApplication"
         main-class=
           "pl.package.Main"
         width="300"
         height="300">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

This below tag should not be within `<resources></resources>` :

```
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
```

Comment: Just try to remove the myjnlp.jnlp from href and test whether it's working or not ?

Comment: Read this documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html

Comment: I noticed that I can't open my jar by double clicking it. It only works when I run it through cmd. I'm also getting a warning "Loading FXML document with JAVAFX API of version 11.0.1 by JAVAFX runtime  of version 8.0.211. I always had this warning, but never had any problems due to it.

Comment: @AnishB.I probably read all of the documentation available on this. Is it possible that I need to sign my jar file with some trusted certificate? I just self- signed it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187520/signing-jar-file.

Comment: Actually, according to the specification, `<security>` needs to come *before* `<resources>`.